What is the name of this sound effect?
I've been having a lot of trouble finding the name of this sound effect. Please someone let me know the name.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PwibUOdPagNqzOotjs37hUrR3NSbBOL0/view?usp=sharing

Do you have any raw signal of this? Otherwise it is just two tones overlayed

Five nights at Freddy’s sequel ambience



